# Editing database in option tag with PHP

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

AUTHORS

```
<select name="author" >
    <?php
    $res = getAuthor();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['author_ID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['author_name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

AUTHORS FUNCTION()

```
function editArticle()
{
$id = $_GET['editArticle'];
        $title = ($_POST['pTitle']);
        $post = ($_POST['tArea']);
        $date = ($_POST['date']);
        $author = ($_POST['author_name']);
        $url = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']);
        $sum = addslashes($_POST['summary']);
        $col = $_POST['column_name'];
        if (isset($title) && isset($post))
{
mysql_query("update `articles` set title='$title', author_ID='$author', post='$post', 
        date = '$date', url = '$url', summary = '$sum', col_name = '$col' where article_ID = '$id' ") or
        die(mysql_error());
}

}
```

MAIN PROBLEM:

This is just an example of what I want the outcome to be.

I have this table where database is shown:

```
eg:
NAME:   SEX:
carlo   male         
-(btn)edit|dete
```

When I press edit, it goes to the edit page and it should look like this

```
NAME: carlo
SEX: <option >male</option>
     <option >female</option>

      (btn)UPDATE
```

but when it goes to the edit page, there are no values to be edited. Just blank text areas, and my "Sex" text ares is in option tag, so there are 2 type to choose from, so how can I get the value MALE from the database into the edit page?

So how do I make it so that when I go to edit the page, the dropdown is already selected to the item which it was when I added it? (In other words if they selected male in the add page, male will be automatically selected in the edit page).

Comment: Perhaps you should be looking for `$_POST['author']` instead of `$_POST['author_name']`.

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: @MarkParnell my page's datas are from my database, i have author database which will be included in the edit page, ughhh i dont know what to do :( its so hard to explain. :(

Comment: @ShivanRaptor im sorry, i dont understand??

Comment: @CarloViloria those functions should NOT be used, as they contain major problems. Replace them with MySQLi or PDO libraries.

Answer (score 1):

name of select box is author so on saving data it must be `$_POST['author']` not `$_POST['author_name']`